# How can I hide the text box in jquery for initial loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am working in this project where I face this issue. My code works when I click after loading.
I have used id for each user. This is the code for active/inactive users. I passed the id to each textbox and span. It is not working. Give some ideas on how to fix this issue. 
PHP Code:

```
    <!--top section start-->
<?php $this->load->view("header");?>
    <div id="wrapper" style="height: auto;">
         <div class="user_intro">
            <table  width="600" height="300">
             <th style="text-align:left;">First Name</th>
             <th style="text-align:left;">Email</th>
             <th style="text-align:center;">Active Status </th>
         <?php 
        foreach($result as $user)
        {?>
             <tr>
                 <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>siteadmin/home/userdetail?userid=<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>"><?php echo $user->first_name;?></a></td>
                 <td style="text-align:left;"><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>siteadmin/home/userdetail?userid=<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>"><?php echo $user->email;?></a></td>
                 <?php if ($user->status == 1) { ?>
                 <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" id="<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>" value="" class="on" onclick="togglestyle(this,this.id)" /> </td>              
                 <td><span id="reason_<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $user->reason; ?>" /> </span></td>
                <?php } 
                else {?>
                 <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" id="<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>" value="" class="off" onclick="togglestyle(this,this.id)" /> </td>   
                 <td><span id="reason_<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $user->reason; ?>" /> </span></td>
                 <?php } ?>
             </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!--fotter section start-->

</div> <?php $this->load->view("footer"); ?>
```

javascript code i have added in header file.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function togglestyle(el, id) {
    if (el.className == "on") {
        $("#reason_" + id).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "statuson",
            data: "userid=" + id,
            success: function (html) {
                if (html == 'true') {
                    el.className = "off";

                }
            },
        });
    } else {
        $("#reason_" + id).hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "statusoff",
            data: "userid=" + id,
            success: function (html) {
                if (html == 'true') {
                    el.className = "on";
                }
            },
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What you need finally..??

Comment: i need to hide the text box at initial loading

Comment: then you need to pass default id and el ..right..??

Comment: set the textbox style="display:none" you don't need JavaScript for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add "display:none;" for the element you want to hide in initial loading.

Like:

```
<span id="reason_<?php echo $user->user_id; ?>" style="display:none;">
```

Then your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple...on document load call the function with default values like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         togglestyle(el,id); //Here el,id are default values for those you need to hide initially
    });
</script>
```

or if you want to hide all the textboxes initially then try like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span[id^='reason'] input[type='text']").hide();
})
```

Comment: What are el & id ?  Anticipating OP question

Comment: As I said those are the dafault values

Comment: Have you passed default values that are existing..??and also try with my edit alternatively

Comment: I also gave the same answer but in jquery....i think without modifying your html just paste this script,you can get....But mine is also same

Answer (score 0):

Use this one in your div style="display:none;

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("input[name='multiple_location']").on('change', function () {
    if (jQuery('input[name="multiple_location"]:checked').val()=='yes') {
    jQuery("#primary_location_text").css('visibility', '');
    } else {

    jQuery("#primary_location_text").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add explanation with the code so that the answer is more meaningful.